# Tablesorter Pager Options Set Default Rows To 5

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, sql, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to get tablesorter to only display 5 results for every page, rather than the default 10. I saw a similar question on here but the solution wasn't working for me.

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    // define pager options
    var pagerOptions = {
        // target the pager markup - see the HTML block below
        container: $(".pager"), size: 5,
        // output string - default is '{page}/{totalPages}'; possible variables: {page}, {totalPages}, {startRow}, {endRow} and {totalRows}
        output: '{startRow} - {endRow} / {filteredRows} ({totalRows})',
        // if true, the table will remain the same height no matter how many records are displayed. The space is made up by an empty
        // table row set to a height to compensate; default is false
        fixedHeight: true,
        // remove rows from the table to speed up the sort of large tables.
        // setting this to false, only hides the non-visible rows; needed if you plan to add/remove rows with the pager enabled.
        removeRows: false,
        // go to page selector - select dropdown that sets the current page
        cssGoto: '.gotoPage'
    };

    $("#Test")
        .tablesorter({
            theme: 'blue',
            dateFormat: "mmddyy",
            widgets: ['zebra', 'filter', 'pager', 'columns'],
            widgetOptions: {
                // output default: '{page}/{totalPages}'
                // possible variables: {page}, {totalPages}, {filteredPages}, {startRow}, {endRow}, {filteredRows} and {totalRows}
                pager_output: '{startRow} - {endRow} / {filteredRows} ({totalRows})', // '{page}/{totalPages}'
                pager_removeRows: false,

                // include child row content while filtering, if true
                filter_childRows: true,
                // class name applied to filter row and each input
                filter_cssFilter: 'tablesorter-filter',
                // search from beginning
                filter_startsWith: false,
                // Set this option to false to make the searches case sensitive 
                filter_ignoreCase: true
            }
        })
        .tablesorterPager(pagerOptions);
});
</script>
```

I'd really like help on this. The default always seems to be 10 rows, even though I've specified 5. 5 works when I select it from the pager drop-down menu, but it is not the default when loading the tables.

```
 <select class="gotoPage2" aria-disabled="false"></select>
        <img class="first disabled" title="First page" alt="First" src="~/Content/images/first.png" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="true" />
        <img class="prev disabled" title="Previous page" alt="Prev" src="~/Content/images/prev.png" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="true" />
        <span class="pagedisplay"></span>
        <!--

        this can be any element, including an input 

        -->
        <img class="next" title="Next page" alt="Next" src="~/Content/images/next.png" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" />
        <img class="last" title="Last page" alt="Last" src="~/Content/images/last.png" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" />
        <select class="pagesize">
            <option selected="selected" value="5">5</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="30">30</option>
            <option value="40">40</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably got an answer long ago, but just in case
You need to change your Select options to reflect the new paging

```
<select class="pagesize">
        <option selected="selected" value="5">5</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="25">25</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It looks like it's more of an issue on the PHP side, not the HTML side